# Best way to delete a record in phpMyAdmin database in this case?

Tags: php, mysql

If I delete a record from phpMyAdmin, then that record's unique ID is gone forever, which is a problem for me.

I have a table to display to my customers, and if an unique ID is gone, then the number's sequence is broken, like this: 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 11, etc.

So, how do I delete a record without affecting the sequence?

Or should I just use this script for table numbering:

```
$number = 1;

<td>$number++</td>
```

It will automatically increment the numbers. But, I still prefer the unique ID, any possible way?

Comment: Why are you using the unique ID as an 'counter' in your table. If you need to list them with a sequential number, just use a <ol> or indeed use a counter.

Comment: Is it a problem for you if IDs are deleted inbetween? That's how it usually is done and it should not affect automatic incrementation

Comment: Offcourse you could renumber every item when you delete an item. But: 1)How would you reference before and after the deletion to the same file? 2) Lets say you'll have 10k records with nice indexes on the unique id.... at every deletion the index needs to be rebuild.... Not very smart.

Comment: PHPMyAdmin *is not* a database. It is a web interface for your MySQL database.

Comment: I just said table to make things easy @sturb. 

So, i should use the code in the question for numbering?

Comment: @Rohit Choudhary it is not easy to delete the row without deleting the column. but if you want to keep the Unique ID the you can just use update query on that particular row. with this the unique id will not be deleted but the other column will have empty val.

Comment: yes, you should use the numbering you profided, or a better way of numbering. MySQL and unique Id's were not made to to be use as a counter nor numbering system. That would always be the job of the programmer to provide

Comment: You've already been told that this is a really bad idea; it really is a really really bad idea.... unique id should never be anything other than a unique id, you should not rely on them to be contiguous

Answer (score 0):

Don't use database unique identifier to display order of numbers in your php /html page. Instead , use local counter variable.